# Favstats (R-Mosaic) returns an error due to non numeric variables although variables are only numeric

Tags: r, r-mosaic

I am trying to get Favstats to work.
I am using a "normal" Dataset with numeric variables that I have loaded in with:

```
ALLBUS2018 <- read.csv("~/Desktop/ALLBUS2018.csv", sep="")
```

When I use Favstats on one of the variables the following happens:

```
fav_stats(~ ep01, data = ALLBUS2018, na.rm = TRUE)
Fehler in fav_stats(~ep01, data = ALLBUS2018, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  Objekt 'pairlist' kann nicht nach 'double' umgewandelt werden
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:
In fav_stats(~ep01, data = ALLBUS2018, na.rm = TRUE) :
  Auto-converting formula to numeric.
```

I have re-installed the Dataset and deleted R completly.
A friend of mine gets a correct output with the same input and no other data in R.
I have tried as.numeric and sapply(ALLBUS2018, function(txt) eval(parse(text=txt)))
[Here you see another Error Message I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia2CO.png)

Here you can find the data used:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fa9hplvk2j6q1cl/ALLBUS2018.csv?dl=0

Thanks for your help!
HS

Comment: Same Problem with median:
> median(~rechts, data=ALLBUS2018)
Fehler in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame

Comment: Hi Hans. Welcome to SO. This question is difficult to answer because it does not feature a minimal, reproducible example. Please see this guide:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example
and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: R might be reading all your csv data as character data. You could try `readr::read_csv()` instead of `base::read.csv()`

Comment: Sorry, I have added the data so that the example should be reproducable.

Comment: Could you show me the full codeline to load the document with readr:read_csv() ?
It does not seem to work for me.

Comment: Hi Hans, turns out that wasn't your problem. Check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

### You're making two mistakes

1. Your file is not a `.csv` - it's plaintext delimited by spaces, rather than commas. For this reason, `read.csv` is returning a column vector of massive strings.
2. Your syntax is wrong inside `mosaic::fav_stats`- you should be doing `ALLBUS2018$ep01`, rather than `~ep01, data = ALLSBUS2018`, which is interpreted as `fav_stats(x = ~ep01, data = ALLBUS2018)`. In this case, `x` is the wrong type (a formula object) and data is passed as an additional argument via `...` and subsequently ignored. Check the help via `?mosaic::favstats` for more info on this.

#### This code should work

The names in your file are hard to read through the default `read.table` methods, so I've done that in a separate step.

```r
require("mosaic")

csv_file <- ('"V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" "V5" "V6" "V7" "V8" "V9" "V10"
"1" NA "za_nr" "doi" "version" "respid" "eastwest" "german" "ep01" "ep03" "ep04"
"2" 1 "5270" "doi:10.4232/1.13250" "2.0.0 (2019-03-26)" "1" "1" "1" "1" "2" "2"
"3" 2 "5270" "doi:10.4232/1.13250" "2.0.0 (2019-03-26)" "2" "2" "1" "2" "4" "3"
"4" 3 "5270" "doi:10.4232/1.13250" "2.0.0 (2019-03-26)" "3" "1" "1" "2" "2" "3"
"5" 4 "5270" "doi:10.4232/1.13250" "2.0.0 (2019-03-26)" "4" "2" "1" "2" "2" "3"
"6" 5 "5270" "doi:10.4232/1.13250" "2.0.0 (2019-03-26)" "5" "2" "1" "3" "2" "3"
"7" 6 "5270" "doi:10.4232/1.13250" "2.0.0 (2019-03-26)" "6" "1" "1" "1" "3" "3"
"8" 7 "5270" "doi:10.4232/1.13250" "2.0.0 (2019-03-26)" "7" "1" "1" "3" "2" "3"
"9" 8 "5270" "doi:10.4232/1.13250" "2.0.0 (2019-03-26)" "8" "1" "1" "2" "3" "3"
"10" 9 "5270" "doi:10.4232/1.13250" "2.0.0 (2019-03-26)" "9" "1" "1" "1" "2" "4"')

ALLBUS2018 <- read.table(text = csv_file, sep = " ") # <- for the purpose of this example
# ALLBUS2018 <- read.table(file = "ALLBUS2018.csv", sep = " ") <- what you should do

### Fix row & colnames
colnames(ALLBUS2018) <- ALLBUS2018[1,]
ALLBUS2018 <- ALLBUS2018[-1,]
rownames(ALLBUS2018) <- ALLBUS2018[,1]
ALLBUS2018 <- ALLBUS2018[,-1]

# This syntax is wrong:
try(mosaic::fav_stats(~ep01, data = ALLBUS2018, na.rm = TRUE))
#> Warning in mosaic::fav_stats(~ep01, data = ALLBUS2018, na.rm = TRUE): Auto-
#> converting formula to numeric.
#> Error in mosaic::fav_stats(~ep01, data = ALLBUS2018, na.rm = TRUE) : 
#>   'language' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

# This syntax is right:
mosaic::fav_stats(ALLBUS2018$ep01, na.rm = TRUE)
#> Warning in mosaic::fav_stats(ALLBUS2018$ep01, na.rm = TRUE): Auto-converting
#> character to numeric.
#>  min Q1 median Q3 max     mean       sd n missing
#>    1  1      2  2   3 1.888889 0.781736 9       0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Hans. I'm glad it helped. If this answered your question, could you accept it as the answer? This helps other users to find the answers they are looking for. Comments are generally used for further discussion